# Mavericks NSUserNotification not sending when app not main

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Notifications are delivering normal when the app is the main app, but when it loses focus notifications aren't getting delivered. I've tried logging calls from `(BOOL)userNotificationCenter:shouldPresentNotification:` and it i'm not getting anything at all when in the background, but logs as expected when main.

Code:

```
NSUserNotification * note = [[NSUserNotification alloc] init];
NSUserNotificationCenter * unc = [NSUserNotificationCenter defaultUserNotificationCenter];
unc.delegate = self;

note.title = track.title;
note.subtitle = track.artist;

[unc deliverNotification:note];
```

Delegate method

```
- (BOOL)userNotificationCenter:(NSUserNotificationCenter *)center shouldPresentNotification:(NSUserNotification *)notification {
    return YES;
}
```

---

**Edit**

I added a  breakpoint before `[unc deliverNotification:note];` and after i resume, the notification always works. Whaaa?

Answer (score 0):

Try getting rid of `unc.delegate = self;`

Comment: Ever since i upgraded to mavericks i've needed to set the delegate and provide the above delegate method to even get anything at all to show up. Not sure why.

Comment: It may be that something null is bugging it up. Try NSLog(@"%@", note) to see if anything seems strange. I once had to explicitly state hasActionButton = NO for the notification to appear.

Comment: Just to make sure, you did set the delegate something like this as well? @interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate, NSUserNotificationCenterDelegate> {

Comment: Ya, got the delegate set up that way. Tried messing with the action button prop. and setting any null strings to an empty string, but it didn't help.

Comment: Check this out: just set a breakpoint before the `[unc deliverNotification:note];` line and when i press resume the notification works. Why would it do that?

Comment: Hmm. This is weird. It works for me but I'm not using the unc middleman. 
    NSUserNotification *notification = [[NSUserNotification alloc] init];

    notification.title = @"title";

    notification.subtitle = @"subtitle"];

    [[NSUserNotificationCenter defaultUserNotificationCenter] deliverNotification:notification];